# EF Core Cosmos DB persists DateTime as Local instead of UTC

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, azure-cosmosdb

I have an object, let's call it `MyMainAggregate` for simplicity. This object has a record called `TimeSlot` which has two members, one `DateTime` called Start and one `TimeSpan` called Duration.

The `DateTime` for the `TimeSlot` object is set to `Utc`, and my tests confirm that the `.Kind is Utc`.

However, when I check CosmosDb document, it displays the DateTime as the Local version, however, it has the `Z` attached to it. For example, `"Start": "2022-12-09T11:00:00Z"`. `11:00:00` is Local. The correct time should've looked like `16:00:00Z`.

I can't figure out what the heck is going on and testing DbContext is a royal nightmare.
I am thinking, as the last line of defense, to create an Interceptor and double check again that the date is correct, but it seems like an overkill when I am already setting the Date to Utc.

Has anyone ran into this same issue?

[UPDATE]

I ran the Cosmos Emulator locally and it is working as expected, Local times are properly being saved as `Utc` by using a `Converter<DateTime, string>`. However, when I pushed the code to the `dev` environment, I still see Local time with an attached 'Z'.

Answer (score 2):

Welp! The issue was pretty straightforward. This is why you should never assume anything.

The code is working as expected. What I never took in consideration is that, effectively, my pods (k8s) were using UTC as the local time. So, rightfully so, 11:00:00Z was correct, because I was setting an appointment to 11AM, at UTC.

Always check what's the Local time of your services/pods.